# How to render 2-D array using *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am working on rendering a menu with a submenu using Angular7 *ngFor and got a problem to render a 2D array. My json data is like this:

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Talent",
        "color" : "",
        "subItems" : [],
        "icon" : ""
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Connections",
        "color" : "",
        "isActivated" : false,
        "subItems" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name": "Pipelines",
                "color": "",
                "subItems" :[],
                "icon" : "fa fa-caret-down"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "name": "Requisition",
                "color": "",
                "subItems" :[],
                "icon" : ""
            },
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "name": "Projects",
                "color": "",
                "subItems" :[],
                "icon" : ""
            }
        ],
        "icon" : ""
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Intelligence",
        "color" : "",
        "isActivated" : false,
        "subItems" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name": "Companies",
                "color": "",
                "subItems" :[],
                "icon" : "fa fa-caret-down"
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "name": "Schools",
                "color": "",
                "subItems" :[],
                "icon" : ""
            }
        ],
        "icon" : ""
      },
     ...
}
```

The Menu bar I want to create, the structure is pretty much like this:

https://codepen.io/marong125/pen/wOZgGz

I have reorganize the data and stored in a 2D array subItems like this:

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(2)]
0: Array(3)
0: {id: 1, name: "Pipelines", color: "", subItems: Array(0), icon: "fa fa-caret-down"}
1: {id: 2, name: "Requisition", color: "", subItems: Array(0), icon: ""}
2: {id: 3, name: "Projects", color: "", subItems: Array(0), icon: ""}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, name: "Companies", color: "", subItems: Array(0), icon: "fa fa-caret-down"}
1: {id: 2, name: "Schools", color: "", subItems: Array(0), icon: ""}
length: 2
```

I have created the nagivation part, however the submenu part works not very well. when I do like this:

```
  <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let navItem of navItems" (click)="expand(navItem.name, $event.target)">
                <a href="#">{{navItem.name}}<span id="upDownIcons"><i *ngIf="navItem.subItems.length !== 0" [ngClass]="navIcons?.arrowDown" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
          <ul>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of subItems; let i = index">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of subItem; let j = index">
                    <li ><a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></li>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

it render like this: (gives each menu items the same submenu): 
[image]

Anyone has better solutions to render 2D array correctly? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the `subItems` array of `navItem` and the same for `subItem`.

```
<li class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let navItem of navItems" (click)="expand(navItem.name, $event.target)">
  <a href="#">{{navItem.name}}<span id="upDownIcons"><i *ngIf="navItem.subItems.length !== 0" [ngClass]="navIcons?.arrowDown" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
  <ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of navItem.subItems; let i = index"> // Iterate over subItems of navItem
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of subItem.subItems; let j = index"> // The same here
        <li ><a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></li>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi ritaj, thank you for the answer. However, after I modified the code the dropdown menu cannot be open. There is no console errors. my navItems are the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your `navItems` and use its `index` to iterate over its `subItems`

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let navItem of navItems;let i = index" (click)="expand(navItem.name, $event.target)">
            <a href="#">{{navItem.name}}<span id="upDownIcons"><i *ngIf="navItem.subItems.length !== 0" [ngClass]="navIcons?.arrowDown" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
      <ul>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of subItems[i]; let j = index">

                <li ><a href="#">{{item.name}}</a></li>

        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Sarthak, I have put your code, however, the dropdown menu cannot open. There is no console error

Comment: Can you share your expand function.

Comment: expand(itemName, target): void {
    const currentItem = this.navItems.filter(item => item.name === itemName);
    this.itemName = itemName;
    let currTarget = null;
    if (currentItem[0].subItems.length !== 0) {
      if (target.tagName === 'A') {
        currTarget = target.parentNode;
      } else {
        currTarget = target;
      }
      currTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    }
  }

Comment: i would recommend to debug the problem by applying your `active` class directly over the correct html element instead of toggling it